# Calculating camera distance so that entity takes certain space on screen

Tags: opengl, camera, distance

I have a simple OpenGL space with the frustum angle at 60 degrees (horizontal), Z_near 0.1 and Z_Far 100.
I also have a square (just 2 triangles) that is always oriented perpendicular to the camera. In fact I just don't apply the view or projection transform to it - only model matrix transform, which ensures that it's always in front of the camera (I want to only change Z coord to get it away from the camera).
The square dimensions are 1.0 x 1.0

the viewport is 1024x768 pixels

How do I calculate the distance it needs to go from the camera, so the square takes exactly 0.25 the width of the screen?

Comment: If you don't apply the projection matrix to the square, you will get an implicit orthogonal projection and the size of the square will not change with distance at all. Actually, zou can directlz draw the rectangle in NDC coordinates and just choose a z which is convenient (if you needit for depth testing etc.)

Comment: 1. have no idea how you getting your perspective but note `gluPerspective` uses `FOVy` mening its vertical angle not horizontal so if the case for you too you need to use aspect ratio to obtain the horizontal angle from vertical `FOVx/FOVy = resolution_x/resolution_y`... 2. as previous comment says without applying projection this will not work 3. use triangle similarity you know that `visual_x_half_size/z = tan(FOVx/2.0)`  and `visual_y_half_size/z = tan(FOVy/2.0)` ... so for visual size use 1.0 and `1.0*xs/ys` or `1.0*ys/xs` and the mesh size and for `z` the distance from camera and `znear`